# Building workflow with automated builds

Tags: testing, build, compilation, automation, gitlab-ci

### I have a question about workflow with docker and gitlab-ci or automated builds in general.

This is how I am imagine how a build should look like↓.
[image: this i what i want]

**How to do it with gitlab-ci ?**
I know how to do one of this tasks, but I don't know how to.
In my imagination i would need more than one base image.

Maybe I am missunderstanding the hole thing.
**How should this process be done in general ?**

Thx four your help

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is very general, I will answer it with an example.

Consider a imaginary C++ project, which contains the code, a *Makefile* which creates the executable "app" and this Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
ADD ./app /app
CMD ["/app"]
```

To build the application and the docker image as you said, you could use a GitLab CI config like this:

```
stages:
  - test
  - build
  - docker

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - make test

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - make
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./app

docker:
  stage: docker
  dependencies:
    - build
  script:
    - docker build -t your-repo/image-name:latest .
    - docker push your-repo/image-name:latest
```

#### Explanation

This CI file creates three jobs: "*test*", "*build*" and "*docker*". "test" runs "make test" to execute any imaginary tests our codebase might have. If they suceed, the GitLab runner will execute the next job, "build".

"build" builds the application by calling "make". We expect *make* to create a file "app" in the current directory, which is our compiled application that will run in the container. The section "artifacts" states that we want to keep this resulting file, since we need it for the next job.

The next job "docker" has a section "dependencies"; in this section we state that this job depends on the output of the job called "build", which created our file "app" before. Then we first build the docker image using *docker build* and push it as usual.

---

As said before, these are just examples, and especially the *script* sections will greatly differ based on your projects and your runner config. See the [official CI documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html) for all possibilities.

Comment: Tanks for your answer. But I have still a question, where is the docker command coming from you use a ubuntu image.

Comment: @AceofSpade Using the Ubuntu docker image for your application is just an example. The GitLab CI commands here are intended to be run by a shell runner outside of a docker container. If you intend to build a docker image inside a docker container, refer to the official documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-in-docker-executor